# Increment Group Number based on row value SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, count, group-by, sql-order-by, partition

I have two tables that aren't really associated, but need to be combined. So I'm using union all on the two tables. The unioned tables are ordered by date, so rows from one table are dispersed among rows from the other table. What I need to do is get a running count of a column so I can group elements.

To explain further, table A holds dates of when a container is emptied, while table B holds daily entries for content of the container. I need to union the two tables so I have one table where I can get the sum of the information for a container before the container is emptied.

So I need something like this:

**Table A**:

```
Location_ID     Empty Date
123             3/2/13
123             3/10/13
123             4/1/13
```

**Table B**:

```
PSI             Entry Date      Location_ID
120             2/28/13         123 (same for all)
130             3/1/13 
100             3/8/13
110             3/9/13
200             3/18/13
180             3/20/13
```

So the unioned table after some magic would look like:

**Table C...**:

```
Location_ID     Date        PSI      Emptied   
123             2/28/13     120      0
123             3/1/13      130      0
123             3/2/13      null     1
123             3/8/13      100      0
123             3/9/13      110      0
123             3/10/13     null     1
123             3/18/13     200      0
123             3/20/13     180      0
123             4/1/13      null     1
```

What I need to do is have a grouping such that I can have a table like this

**Table C_b**

```
Location_ID     Date        PSI      Emptied   Group
123             2/28/13     120      0         1
123             3/1/13      130      0         1
123             3/2/13      null     1         1
123             3/8/13      100      0         2
123             3/9/13      110      0         2
123             3/10/13     null     1         2
123             3/18/13     200      0         3
123             3/20/13     180      0         3
123             4/1/13      null     1         3
```

How can I get that grouping in that way? I have to make it work in SQL Server 2008. I have tried using Count, and Rank, and Row_Number. But the problem with those is that it won't do a running count, it will just say the total count in each row.

Comment: This would be so, so, so much easier in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Also, these are terrible date formats.

Comment: I actually had it running perfectly in 2012, but then we found that our production database was running 2008, so we had to downgrade our dev database. So I hear you.
Also, note that that data isn't exactly representative of actual format of my data. I simplified it for explaining the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(
EntryDate DATE NOT NULL,
Emptied BIT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @MyTable (EntryDate,Emptied)
VALUES 
('2013-01-01',0),
('2013-01-02',0),
('2013-01-03',1),
('2013-01-04',0),
('2013-01-05',0),
('2013-01-06',1),
('2013-01-07',0),
('2013-01-08',0),
('2013-01-09',1);

DECLARE @TableWithRowNum TABLE(
EntryDate DATE NOT NULL,
Emptied BIT NOT NULL,
RowNum INT PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO @TableWithRowNum (EntryDate,Emptied,RowNum)
SELECT  crt.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY crt.EntryDate) AS RowNum
FROM    @MyTable crt;

WITH RecCTE
AS(
    SELECT  
        crt.EntryDate,
        crt.Emptied,
        crt.RowNum,
        1 AS Grp
    FROM    @TableWithRowNum crt
    WHERE   crt.RowNum=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  
        crt.EntryDate,
        crt.Emptied,
        crt.RowNum,
        CASE WHEN prev.Emptied=1 THEN prev.Grp+1 ELSE prev.Grp END
    FROM    @TableWithRowNum crt INNER JOIN RecCTE prev ON crt.RowNum=prev.RowNum+1
)
SELECT * FROM RecCTE 
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0); -- Default value for MAXRECURSION is 100
GO
```

Results:

```
EntryDate  Emptied RowNum Grp
---------- ------- ------ ---
2013-01-01 0       1      1
2013-01-02 0       2      1
2013-01-03 1       3      1
2013-01-04 0       4      2
2013-01-05 0       5      2
2013-01-06 1       6      2
2013-01-07 0       7      3
2013-01-08 0       8      3
2013-01-09 1       9      3
```

Comment: Is the HASH JOIN useful only because your demo uses a table variable with no statistics? I suggest this shouldn't be part of the answer, even if your demo doesn't produce an optimal plan without it, or at the very least explain why you've listed an explicit join hint. These should be reserved for very particular scenarios when all of the ins and outs are known.

Comment: Yep. I forget that hint. In this scenario this hint isn't useful.

Comment: Awesome, that did it. I haven't done things with CTE's before, so I only kinda understand what just happened. Got it to work however. So that is something that I'm gonna have to research more of to understand. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't forget `MAXRECURSION` query hint. Default value is 100 and if you have more than 100 rows (ex. 101 rows) then you will get this error `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.` [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)

Comment: so by setting that maxrecursion value to 0, we're basically getting rid of the default and allowing infinite (well, to a point) rows to be processed?

Comment: "When 0 is specified, no limit is applied."